# React native, click event parameter value not set unique in foreach loop

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am new in react-native, i have stuck in one problem.
i have registration page, where there is two section first one is parent registration and second one is student registration.
so parents can add no of child registration form as per there requirement.now if parents wants to remove any child form or block, there is remove information functionality, but when i bind my remove button click event in foreach loop, **all the button's parameter value remaining same**.so every time when i click on remove button it remove last form.

**Here is My code**

```
export default class SignUp extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    {

    }

    this.index = 1;

    this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);

    this.state = {
      username: '', password: '', email: '', phone_number: '', registrationData: [],
      valueArray: [], key: 0, index: 0
    }
  }

  AddMore = async () => {
    try {
      var data = this.state.index + 1;
      this.setState({ index: data });
    }
    catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }

    try {

      this.animatedValue.setValue(0);
      let newlyAddedValue = { index: this.index }

      this.setState({ disabled: true, valueArray: [...this.state.valueArray, newlyAddedValue] }, () => {
        Animated.timing(
          this.animatedValue,
          {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 500,
            useNativeDriver: true
          }
        ).start(() => {
          this.index = this.index + 1;
          this.setState({ disabled: false });

        });
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      alert("Error " + error);
    }
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Registration',
  }

  onRemoveBlock = (key) => {
    try {
      var r = this.state.valueArray;
      var d = r.length - key;
      r.splice(d, 1);
      this.setState({ valueArray: r });
    }

    catch (error) {
      alert(error)
    }
  }

  render() {

    let data = [{
      value: 'Male',
    }, {
      value: 'Female'
    }];

    this.position = 0;
    let newArray = this.state.valueArray.map((item, key) => {
      this.position = key + 1;

      return (
        <View style={styles.container} key={key} >

          <ScrollView>

            <Button
              title={'Remove'}
              onPress={() => this.onRemoveBlock(this.position)}
            />

            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder={'First Name'}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              placeholderTextColor='white'
              onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('childfirstname' + this.position, val)}
            />

          </ScrollView>
        </View>

      );
    });
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>
          <Text h1>Parent Registration</Text>

        <TextInput
            style={styles.input}
            placeholder='First Name'
            autoCapitalize="none"
            placeholderTextColor='white'
            onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('firstname', val)}
          />


          <Text h1>Student Registration</Text>
          <View style={styles.container} key={123} >

            <ScrollView>

              <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder={'First Name'}
                autoCapitalize="none"
                placeholderTextColor='white'
                onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('childfirstname0', val)}
              />

            </ScrollView>
          </View>

          <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 4 }}>
            {
              newArray
            }
          </View>
          <Text>{"\n"}</Text>

        </ScrollView>

        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.8} style={styles.btn} disabled={this.state.disabled} onPress={this.AddMore}>
          <Image source={require('./assets/add.png')} style={styles.btnImage} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
    }
```

Comment: add some more info. code will be helpful :)

Comment: In order to properly help you, you will need to post some code, your React Code to create the Component in this case. The likely issue is you are missing a required "key={uniqekey} field but there is no way to know without seeing your code.

Comment: @deadcoder0904
i have added code, please check and let me know what changes i have to do

Comment: @SteveB, please let me know, still i am facing issue.

Comment: Your remote button doesn't have a key assigned to it. Add a key={this.position} assuming this.position is unique and try that out.

Comment: @SteveB, thanks for the suggestion but I found the issue in mine code.

Comment: @Vishalmodi key's and index's are important in React-Native. Glad you got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I click on the remove button, the value of text input was updated with other textfield because of the key. it removes the section which I want to remove so everything works fine, I just need to manage to the index of control properly.

**I have updated code and now it is working fine**

I just need to assign index value rather than the key to a position in valuearray loop

```
let newArray = this.state.valueArray.map((item, key) => {
      //this.position = key + 1;
      this.position=item.index;
      return (
        <View style={styles.container} key={this.position} >

          <ScrollView>

            <Button
              title={'Actual Key -> '+item.index +' key -> '+key}
              onPress={() => this.onRemoveBlock(key)}
              key={key}
            />

            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder={'First Name'+this.position}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              placeholderTextColor='white'
              onChangeText={val => this.onChangeText('childfirstname' + this.position, val)}
            />

          </ScrollView>
        </View>

      );
    });
```

so now control value will remain the same always